# 2D HUD over 3D scene

Tags: 2d, 3d, opentk, hud

I'm trying to create a 2D Heads up Display for my players in a 3D OpenTK environment. How I'm doing it is by drawing my 3D elements and then running this code.

```
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.Ortho(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 100);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();
//Disable all depth stuff
GL.DepthMask(false);
GL.Disable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.Disable(EnableCap.CullFace);
//Pass texture to shaders
GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureImg.Handle);
GL.Uniform1(GL.GetUniformLocation(Game.pgmID, "texUnit"), 0.0);
GL.Uniform1(GL.GetUniformLocation(Game.pgmID, "texture"), 1.0);
//Enable vertex attributes
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(Game.attribute_vpos);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(GL.GetAttribLocation(Game.pgmID, "texcoord"));
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
//MVP matrix is only translation of HUD position
Matrix4 c = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y, 0)) * Matrix4.CreateScale(0.1f);
GL.UniformMatrix4(Game.uniform_mview, false, ref c);
//Send vertices and uvs to shader
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(verts.Length * Vector2.SizeInBytes), verts, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(Game.attribute_vpos, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[]
{
    new Vector2(0,0),
    new Vector2(1,0),
    new Vector2(1,1),
    new Vector2(0,1)
};

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(uvs.Length * Vector2.SizeInBytes), uvs, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(GL.GetAttribLocation(Game.pgmID, "texcoord"), 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
//Draw
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, 4);
GL.UseProgram(Game.pgmID);
//Make sure I can render 3D again
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
GL.DepthMask(true);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
```

It works exactly how it's supposed to, except the quad that I draw to the screen is slightly stretched out. It's annoying the absolute heck out of me, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit: Picture**
[image]

Comment: Ypu always create a new array buffer everytime you render something? That's going to take up a lot of memory overtime.

Comment: Are you talking about the UVs? I'll put them in my class instead. It does seem inefficient now that I think about it.

Answer (score 2):

GL.Ortho creates a screen that is as wide and tall as you specified it. In your case both the width and height is 1 unit.

Because your screen is wider than taller, a width unit is bigger than a height unit, and thus the square becomes stretched.

You need to get the screen's sizes, calculate it's aspect ratio (width / height), then you need to set the left clipping plane to `-aspectRatio / 2` and the right to simply `aspectRatio / 2`. You also need to load the ortographic matrix after the identity matrix.

You should store `aspectRatio` somewhere in case you wnt to put something at the edge of the screen, because that's not 1 anymore.

Comment: A simple and well thought out answer, just the kind I like. Up-vote for this one :)

Comment: I just tried what you said, but unfortunately the stretched out quad persists. `GL.Viewport` seemed to have some effect. If I set it to `GL.Viewport(0,0,800,800)` I can render the quad perfectly, but only in the left hundred pixels.

Comment: @Denver do you call GL.Identity before it?

Comment: Yes, I do call `GL.Identity()` before the Ortho call. Which looks like this now. `GL.Ortho(-aspectratio, aspectratio, -aspectratio, aspectratio, 1, 100);`

Comment: @Denver You need to set only the left and right to aspectratio, the top and bottom should be -0.5 and 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching about, the answer was amazingly stupid. All I needed to do was send the translation of my HUD element multiplied by an orthographic matrix to the shader. The code looks like this for other people with my problem.

`Matrix4 c = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y, 0)) * Matrix4.CreateScale(100) * ortho * Matrix4.Identity;
GL.UniformMatrix4(Game.uniform_mview, false, ref c);`